# Bash pass all arguments as one quoted argument to another command

Tags: bash, mingw

I usually do this:

```
git commit -m "My hands are typing words!"
```

I am gettin' tired of that, so I made this batch:

```
@echo off
set var=%*
git commit -m "%var%"
```

Which works as:

```
commit.bat blah blah blah
```

So I can drop the `-m` and the quotes, but it adds `.bat`. When I remove file extension, git Bash tries to interpret the batch as bash. So I need to use bash syntax instead. That's fine, I tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
git commit -m "$@"
```

That doesn't work, it passes arguments as multiple arguments. It invokes this:

```
git commit -m My hands are typing words!
```

I tried to add even more quotes (`git commit -m ""$@""`), no effect.

So how do I convert all arguments to a string that can be passed in bash to another command?

Comment: Use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`. But to be correct, you should use `commit.sh "blah blah blah"` with double quotes around message.

Comment: Eliminating the need for the quotes was my main goal, correct or not.

Comment: Check my answer, on why quotes are important... Of course, if you don't care about that reason, you can use the `"$*"` mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"$*"` instead of `"$@"`.
This sample script should explain it:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo '$*:'
printf "%s\n" $*
echo
echo '"$*":'
printf "%s\n" "$*"
echo
echo '$@:'
printf "%s\n" $@
echo
echo '"$@":'
printf "%s\n" "$@"

$ ./a.sh a b "c    d"             e
$*:
a
b
c
d
e

"$*":
a b c    d e

$@:
a
b
c
d
e

"$@":
a
b
c    d
e
```

But correctly, you should use "$1" & quote your message string before passing to the script.
In above example, you can see that the spaces between c & d are retained, but those between "c d" & e are lost.

Comment: Can the loss of spaces be fixed without quoting the input? Windows batch doesn't have this problem...

Comment: @TomášZato No. The shell drops unquoted spaces before the command even runs. If `cmd.exe` doesn't do that that's a design choice it made.